# Cannot launch AVD in emulator. Location of kernel file

Tags: java, android, adt

I was in trouble with the API, but when I fix it I face a new problem which is something about "kernel file" and its location. When I RUN the app show up to me that message:

> Cannot launch AVD in emulator.
>       Output:
>       emulator: ERROR: This AVD's configuration is missing a kernel file! Please ensure the file "kernel-qemu" is in the same location as your system image.
>       emulator: ERROR: ANDROID_SDK_ROOT is undefined

[image]